# Newest version's not shown on the Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Today I experienced some strange behaviour of the Appstore. We released new update for our app, it became live for couple of hours -> I could see it also in our analytics, but after couple of hours the update was rollbacked & is not accesible on the Appstore anymore, although in iTunes Connect this update is in state **Ready for sale**.

I was looking for reasons why it disappeared from the AppStore, but I couldn't find one.
Our app doesn't provide any in-app purchases, nor any advertisements/iAds.
The only thing I've found on the Itunes Connect was this official explanation in Apple's documentation.

> My app status is Ready for Sale but I cannot see my app on the App Store. Why? 
>   The following factors could prevent your app from showing up on the App Store:
>
> Make sure to check the status of your agreements. If the agreement status is Pending Contract, you may have to agree to the PLA or Paid Applications agreement or complete the associated bank and tax information for that agreement.
>
> Make sure the availability date provided in the Rights and Pricing section is prior to today's date.
>   If the date provided in the Rights and Pricing section is in the past, make sure you made your app available in at least one App Store territory.
>
> If your app was scheduled to go live within the last 24 hours, the app may still be updating in the App Store cache. Once the 24-hour caching window has passed, close and open iTunes and search for your app again. You can also click View in the App Store from the More tab on your app's page in My Apps.

Because the app version went live, I believe we don't apply to any of these points. Furthermore - the dev account is paid & all contracts updated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it was the window cache thing. Update made it to the production, but was rollbacked until the appstore cache system didnt push it to prod again. Strange, but after all Apple made our update available to our users